# Angular Library with proper sub-entries

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, ng-packagr

I am trying to build an Angular library following documentation but unfortunately I am getting some issues while building it.

There are 2 main issues I am facing:

### 1st issue: Modules of the library are exported with full path

`import MyComponentModule from '@my/components/lib/my-component/my-component.module`

while it should be

`import MyComponentModule from '@my/components/my-component`

### 2nd issue: I am unable to compile the app that is using the library

I am getting a compilation error saying that `@my/components/lib/my-component/my-component.module` can't be resolved even though I see it in `node_modules`.

## What am I doing wrong? :(

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "@my/components/*": [
        "projects/components/src/*",
        "projects/components/src"
      ],
      "@my/components": [
        "dist/components/*",
        "dist/components"
      ]
    },
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

```
// projects/components/package.json
{
  "name": "@my/components",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "11",
    "@angular/core": "11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  }
}

// projects/components/ng-package.json
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/components",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
  }
}
```

```
// projects/components/src/public-api.ts
export * from './lib/my-component';

// projects/components/src/lib/my-component/index.ts
export * from './public-api'

// projects/components/src/lib/my-component/public-api.ts
export * from './my-component.module';
export * from './my-component.component';

// projects/components/src/lib/my-component/package.json
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "entryFile": "public-api.ts",
      "cssUrl": "inline"
    }
  }
}
```

Yet, while building the library using the CLI I see it builds 2 things:

- `@my/components`, and
- `@my/components/src/lib/my-component` // Shouldn't this be `@my/components/my-component`?

**Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?**

Comment: The second message seems to result from the first message.

Comment: This section of the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#use-typescript-path-mapping-for-peer-dependencies) might help. The `export` statement in the code uses relative paths, . notation, when paths using @ are used elsewhere.

Comment: I think your first and second problems are related. You are most likely importing your library from source rather than build. Please check that you are importing the library produced by the build.

Answer (score 1):

1. since you are using * it is exporting everything as is, you can specify the file instead.

```
"paths": {
      "@my/components/my-component": [
        "projects/components/src/lib/my-component/public-api.ts",
      ],
    },
```

2. Because of the * there is no default you have to use brackets around it so it can find the reference.

```
import { MyComponentModule } from '@my/components/my-component';
```